# Print result of $body

Tags: nodes

on D7 and I've made this:

```
function project() {
  global $user;
  $uid = $user->uid;
  $name = $user->name;

  $teaser = 0;
  $page = 1;
  $type = 'page';
  $status = 1;
  $format = 3;

  $body = "<script language=\"JavaScript\" src=\"/misc/collapse.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script> ".
                "<div><p>Projects from user ".$name."</p></div>";
}
?>
```

And I need to print the result on the main content of my theme, how can I do it? 
If I do `echo "$body";`I view the result not in the main content but as a single page. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php print $node->body['und'][0]['value'];?>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response.
Added the line but I've blank page. why?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: node in ..
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ....

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `project()` is a page callback, a function that is associated to a path used from the module, and that needs to output what contained in `$body`. In that case, you need to returns its content, and your code should be like the following one.

```
function project() {
  global $user;
  $uid = $user->uid;
  $name = $user->name;

  // The rest of your code.

  return '<script language="JavaScript" src="/misc/collapse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>' . "<div><p>Projects from user $name</p></div>";
}
```

The reason is that [drupal_deliver_html_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7) (indirectly called from index.php) contains the following code.

```
  if (is_int($page_callback_result)) {
    // The page callback returned an integer.

    // …

  elseif (isset($page_callback_result)) {
    // The page callback returned a string or an array.
    // Print anything besides a menu constant, assuming it's not NULL or
    // undefined.
    print drupal_render_page($page_callback_result);
  }
```

If your page callback doesn't return anything, but it just prints its own output, `drupal_render_page()` will not be called, and the output of your page callback will be all the content you see in the page.

Comment: Solved with:
return $body;
Thanks a lot for your help!